# Getting "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.webServer'" while web.config transformation

Tags: .net-core, web-config, web.config-transform

I am doing the web.config transformations. Here is my web.config -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" value="frame-ancestors 'self'" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="https redirect">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
          <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server" >
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Adding HSTS" enabled="true">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
                pattern=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions> 
            <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
          </rule>
        </outboundRules> 
      </rewrite>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Local" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
     <system.web>
         <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
     </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

My web.release.config is same as web.config. And web.Development.config is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when I am publishing using "dotnet publish --configuration Development /p:EnvironmentName=Development" command, it says  `No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.webServer'`
Also while deploying to server I am getiing this -
`[apply APPName_DEV\web.Development.config to APPName_DEV\web.config] W:\Buildnumber\APPName_DEV\web.Development.config:7,7 - No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.webServer'`

Please help me on this, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove `<location>` from your base config or add `<location>` to your development config.

You are trying to replace `<configuration><system.webServer>`
but in your base config you have `<configuration><location><system.webServer>`